# Handle Duplicate insertion node js

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

What is the best way to handle duplicate insertion?

Either we should check before insertion if item already exist then notify user for duplicate entry or we can handle error message and let user know that its a duplicate entry.

Using first approach will cost us an extra database call.

Or if there is any other better approach to handle this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate insertion is at database level.

- Your call to the api must be coming from front end.So you need to
  ensure that duplicate call is avoided at first place e.g you should
  disable the button as soon as user clicks it first time.

Or

- You can add database schema level check like primary key so that if
  duplicate data comes error is thrown and same can be forwarded to
  user.

Or

- add checks mentioned in
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Checking Whether data exists before insertion is  a expensive call and that too you will have to hit on master so try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a primary key based on the data.  If this is not possible with your data then you'll have to query the database before insertion.